# How do I write generics to return arg A if not undefined, and arg B if A is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a really simple function which looks like this:

```
type NotUndefined = string | number | boolean | symbol | object

function ifDefined<A extends undefined, B> (thenThis: A, ifNotThenThis?: B): B
function ifDefined<A extends NotUndefined, B> (thenThis: A, ifNotThenThis?: B): A
function ifDefined<A, B> (thenThis: A, ifNotThenThis?: B) {
  return thenThis === undefined ? ifNotThenThis : thenThis
}

export default ifDefined
```

Essentially, if argument A is not exactly undefined, it will return argument A. If argument A is undefined, it will return argument B.

I thought I was happy with my overload declarations, but when I call it like so:

```
const numBeds = ifDefined(manualNumBeds, autoNumBeds)
```

I get the following error:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(thenThis: undefined, ifNotThenThis?: number | undefined): number', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(thenThis: NotUndefined, ifNotThenThis?: number | undefined): NotUndefined', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NotUndefined'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'NotUndefined'.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use a conditional type as return type :

```js
function ifDefined<A, B = undefined>(
    thenThis: A,
    ifNotThenThis: B = undefined
): A extends undefined ? B : A {
    return thenThis === undefined ? ifNotThenThis : thenThis // compilation error
}

export default ifDefined;
```

Note that the compiler can't check that the returned value match the returned type (see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22735). So we have to cast the returned expression to the returned type or to any:

```js
function ifDefined<A, B = undefined>(
    thenThis: A,
    ifNotThenThis: B = undefined
): A extends undefined ? B : A {
    return (thenThis === undefined ? ifNotThenThis : thenThis) as any
    // or
    //(thenThis === undefined ? ifNotThenThis : thenThis) as A extends undefined ? B : A
}

export default ifDefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

These overloads appear to work as intended:

```
function ifDefined<A extends undefined, B> (a: A, b?: B): B;
function ifDefined<A extends {}, B> (a: A, b?: B): A;

function ifDefined<A, B> (a: A, b?: B) {
  return a === undefined ?  b : a;
}

let x = ifDefined(123, void 0)      // 'number'
let y = ifDefined(void 0, 'hey')    // 'string'
let z = ifDefined(void 0, void 0)   // 'undefined'
```